# image system help

Tags: 7, media

New to Drupal, but am finding it pretty amazing.

I have imported over 4000 articles from another site.  At the moment, I have 'filtered hmtl' switched on for all of these articles.

They have html image code (the images are posted in from an external source)

It looks like this:

```
<img width="350" align="left" src="http://***********" alt="" />
```

I am very happy with the way the image system in Drupal 7 works, but supposing I wanted to apply a style (border, padding etc) to these images, and therefore switch html on the 'full'  what's the best way to go about it?

I don;t want to do anything that would interfere with the core image system.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to look for img tag and attach your class, once you attached the class then use CSS to apply border padding and etc.

Code for adding Class:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {          
     $( "img" ).addClass( "classname" );
}
</script>
```

Where to add this code ?

I will suggest to add this into your content type tpl.php file.

If you don't already have one, create one.

in your theme folder create a new file name it **node--articles.tpl.php**

and past the code into that file.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a node.
 *

?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {          
         $( "img" ).addClass( "classname" );
    }
    </script>
```

**Please note: In  node--articles.tpl.php, rename the articles to your content type machine name.**

Now you can go to your css file and start playing with your class name.

```
.classname {

}
```

**How the code work ?**

When article page is clicked, the javescript code look for img tag and attach the class name into it.